# Understanding geometric argument for $\frac{d}{d\theta} \sin \theta = \cos \theta$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-explanation

I am watching the third lecture in MIT's 18.01 course, and I can't fully understand the geometric argument the professor makes for why the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$. Thsi is difficult to describe without a picture, but I will try my best.

He draws a unit circle with center $0$, and a segment from $0$ to a point $P$ on the boundary of the circle, making angle $\theta$ with a horizontal radial length from the origin. Relative to this segment $OP$, we can move counterclockwise by $\Delta \theta$ to a point $Q$.

The first thing I don't understand is this. He draws a line from $PQ$ and argues that it is approximately perpendicular to $PQ$, and it is perpendicular in the limit. This looks "about perpendicular" to me, so I'm willing to accept that, but I don't understand the comment: "It isn't quite perpendicular because the length between $P$ and $Q$ is non-zero, but in the limit, it's perpendicular."

I don't understand how the limiting condition and the length of $PQ$ comes into play.

Comment: The second comment was just a different way of expressing the first comment. If you can accept "about perpendicular", then you can ignore the second comment.

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what the limit condition is, because it doesn't seem to me that $Q$ is involved in any way. @TonyK

Comment: The limit condition is that $Q$ moves closer and closer to $P$, until "in the limit" $Q=P$.

Comment: The sum of the angles of a triangle is $180°$. What happens to the other two angles if the vertex angle tends to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the circle to have some radius $r$. Then, using cosine rule the length of $PQ$ is given by:
$$PQ=2r\sin\left(\frac {\Delta \theta}{2}\right)$$
Hence, $$\sin\left(\frac {\Delta \theta}{2}\right)=\frac {PQ}{2r}{\tag 1}$$
Also, the angle between $OP$ and $PQ$ is $\frac {\pi}{2}-\frac {\Delta \theta}{2}$, since $\Delta OPQ$ is an isosceles triangle.
Thus, if you let $PQ\to 0$, then consequently $\Delta \theta\to 0$ and hence we get a perfect perpendicular.

In fact, for small $PQ$ we can approximate $(1)$ as:
$$\frac {\Delta \theta}{2}\approx \frac {PQ}{2r}$$
Which means that the angle is given by $\frac {\pi}{2}-\frac {PQ}{r}$.  This makes the limiting angle even clearer.